# Given an array of city, each elements represent the maximum visited times of this city, Each city cannot be visited continuously

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

for example: given an array: array1[3, 1, 7]

so we can visit array2[city3, city1, city3, city1, ....]

we want to return the maximum total visit times, which is the length of the array2.

what algorithm can we use in this question? can anyone give me an coding example? thank you so much!

Comment: its not clear just what are inputs and examples of expected outputs ... I suggest you go into battle and code up some of your ideas and then update with specific answerable nuggets of goodness ... otherwise someone will just close this posting

Comment: You can use a greedy strategy by putting into the priority queue the all cities by their initial visit counts. This way you can greedly always take the first town that has most visits left and that can be visited. Decrease number of visits possible on each access.
You did not provide more info to this problem but there are cases when it is not possible to visit all cities. e.g. arr=[7,1]